# What does this while condition mean?

Tags: python

I'm not so much used to Python and I encountered this code.

What does this condition `y:x,y=y,x%y` mean for the `while` statement?

`x` and `y` are supposed to be integers.

```
def a(x,y):
   while y:x,y=y,x%y
   return x
```

Comment: The condition is only `y`, everything after the `:` is the body of the loop. And yes, this is pretty bad code, demonstrated by the fact that you need to ask this question…

Comment: @deceze oh right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python sometimes can be written in one liners. If you break what you've typed:

```
def a(x,y):
    while y:
        x, y = y, x%y
    return x
```

Which means, while `y` is `True` or `1` (this is met because nothing else is specified as `y==2` or `y ==12310982`... and if you try to make `True` as a number it will return as `1`)

the second statement is defining two variables at the same time `x, y` which is equivalent as the same order after `=` as `y, x%y`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have copied it wrong, it should probably be:

```
def a(x,y):
    while y:
        x,y =y, x%y
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def a(x,y):
  while y:x,y=y,x%y
  return x
```

**Write the code this way**

```
def a(x,y):
   while y:
     x,y=y,x%y
   return x
```

It means nothing but if y > 0 the while loop execute

in `x,y = y, x % y` what is happening here is
`x = y`

and `y = x % y` (which make `y = 0` at some point)